# BeautifulSoup showing different elements in rows when scraping table

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the Compute - Virtual Machine Instances Table from the following URL (they don't have an API):
https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/compute/pricing/#compute-vm

I am using Beautiful Soup and this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



def scrape():
    url = 'https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/compute/pricing/#compute-vm'
    oracle_website = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(oracle_website, "html.parser")

    virtual_machine_table = soup.find("div", class_="rc34w5 rw-neutral-00bg").table
    for compute_products in virtual_machine_table.find_all("tbody"):
        rows = compute_products.find_all("tr")

        print(rows[0])
```

Now if we go through the code, I first go to the URL and access the div which contains the respective table and then go inside the table tag. I then find all the 'tr' tags inside the 'tbody' tags. These tr tags correspond to each row in the table. In the last line, I print the first row of the table which is the row for 'Compute – Ampere A1 – OCPU' product.

If we run this code I get the following result:

```
<tr data-partnumber="B93297">
<td><div>Compute – Ampere A1 – OCPU</div></td>
<td class="rw-theme-40bg"><div data-minrange="3000" data-type="vcpu"><br/>
</div></td>
<td><span data-minrange="3000"><span data-model="pay_as_you_go"></span></span></td>
<td><div>OCPU per hour</div></td>
</tr>
```

Now if we look at this I get the first column for this row is correct and is 'Compute – Ampere A1 – OCPU' The last column is correct and is 'OCPU per hour'. However, the second and third columns have empty divs.

if we use the chrome developer tools and inspect on the first row, the result I should be getting is:

```
<tr data-partnumber="B93297">
<th scope="row"><div>Compute – Ampere A1 – OCPU</div></th>
<td class="rw-theme-40bg"><div data-minrange="3000" data-type="vcpu" class="">$0.01<span></span></div></td>
<td><span data-minrange="3000" class="">$0.01<span></span></span></td>
<td><div>OCPU per hour</div></td>
</tr>
```

Can someone pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Those prices are loaded in from a json file [here](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/pricing/cloud-price-list.json). This is not the most efficient/elegant of code, but you need to add some logic as to pull out the right price for the part numbers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd


jsonData = requests.get('https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/pricing/cloud-price-list.json').json()
currency = 'USD'

#def scrape():
url = 'https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/compute/pricing/#compute-vm'
oracle_website = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(oracle_website, "html.parser")

rows = []
virtual_machine_table = soup.find("div", class_="rc34w5 rw-neutral-00bg").table
for compute_products in virtual_machine_table.find_all("tbody"):
    trs = compute_products.find_all("tr")
    
    for tr in trs:
        vCPUcompPrice = tr.find_all('td')[1]
        
        checkForPartNum = vCPUcompPrice.find('div', {'data-partnumber': re.compile('.*')})
        if checkForPartNum:
            partNumber = checkForPartNum['data-partnumber']
            
        else:
            try:
                partNumber = tr['data-partnumber']
            except:
                partNumber = None
            
        if partNumber == 'B93297':
            compPrice = jsonData['vcpuRangeItems'][partNumber][currency][-1]['value']
            unitPrice = jsonData['vcpuRangeItems'][partNumber][currency][-1]['value']
            
        elif partNumber == None:
            compPrice = 'Free'
            unitPrice = 'Free'
            
        else:
            if partNumber not in jsonData['vcpuItems'].keys():
                compPrice = '-'
            else:
                compPrice = jsonData['vcpuItems'][partNumber][currency]
            
            if partNumber not in jsonData['items'].keys():
                if partNumber not in jsonData['rangeItems'].keys():
                    unitPrice = '-'
                else:
                    unitPrice = jsonData['rangeItems'][partNumber][currency][-1]['value']
            
            else:
                unitPrice = jsonData['items'][partNumber][currency]
        
        
               
        row = {
            'partNumber':partNumber,
            'Product':tr.find_all('td')[0].text,
            'Comparison Price (/vCPU)':compPrice,
            'Unit price':unitPrice,
            'Unit':tr.find_all('td')[-1].text,
             }
        rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_markdown())
|    | partNumber   | Product                                                         | Comparison Price (/vCPU)   | Unit price   | Unit              |
|---:|:-------------|:----------------------------------------------------------------|:---------------------------|:-------------|:------------------|
|  0 | B93297       | Compute – Ampere A1 – OCPU                                      | 0.01                       | 0.01         | OCPU per hour     |
|  1 | B93298       | Compute – Ampere A1 – Memory                                    | -                          | 0.0015       | Gigabyte per hour |
|  2 | B93311       | Compute - Virtual Machine Optimized - X9                        | 0.027                      | 0.054        | OCPU per hour     |
|  3 | B93312       | Compute - Virtual Machine Optimized - X9 - Memory               | -                          | 0.0015       | Gigabyte per hour |
|  4 | B88514       | Compute - Virtual Machine Standard - X7                         | 0.0319                     | 0.0638       | OCPU per hour     |
|  5 | B88516       | Compute - Virtual Machine Dense I/O - X7                        | 0.06375                    | 0.1275       | OCPU per hour     |
|  6 | B93113       | Compute - Standard - E4 - OCPU                                  | 0.0125                     | 0.025        | OCPU per hour     |
|  7 | B93114       | Compute - Standard - E4 - Memory                                | -                          | 0.0015       | Gigabyte per hour |
|  8 | B92306       | Compute - Standard - E3 - OCPU                                  | 0.0125                     | 0.025        | OCPU per hour     |
|  9 | B92307       | Compute - Standard - E3 - Memory                                | -                          | 0.0015       | Gigabyte per hour |
| 10 |              | Compute - Virtual Machine Standard - E2 Micro - Free            | Free                       | Free         | OCPU per hour     |
| 11 | B91372       | Database - Marketplace Compute Image - Microsoft SQL Enterprise | 0.735                      | 1.47         | OCPU per hour     |
| 12 | B91373       | Database - Marketplace Compute Image - Microsoft SQL Standard   | 0.185                      | 0.37         | OCPU per hour     |
| 13 | B94176       | Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - Compute - Standard - X9           | 0.02                       | 0.04         | OCPU per hour     |
| 14 | B94177       | Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - Compute - Standard - X9 - Memory  | -                          | 0.0015       | Gigabyte per hour |
```

Comment: thank you so much! How did you figure out the data was being loaded from a json file?

Comment: just by having a little snoop around to be honest. If you open up Dev Tools (sht-ctrl-i), you can look at the requests being made. When I did that and searched for one of the obsure prices like `"0.06375"`, it found that value coming from a certain request, which was that json file

Comment: The json file is set up a little weird, however, not the worst I've seen. Like I stated, just have to logically work out/find the value based on the part numbers.